# Pandas groupby and sum total of group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame with customer refund reasons. 
It contains these example data rows:

```
    **case_type**       **claim_type**
1   service             service
2   service             service
3   chargeback          service
4   chargeback          local_charges
5   service             supplier_service
6   chargeback          service
7   chargeback          service
8   chargeback          service
9   chargeback          service
10  chargeback          service
11  service             service_not_used
12  service             service_not_used
```

I would like to compare the customer's reason with some sort of labeled reason. This is no problem, but I would also like to see the total number of records in a specific group (customer reason).

```
case_claim_type = df[["case_type", "claim_type"]]
case_claim_type.groupby(by=("case_type", "claim_type"))["case_type"].count()
```

Which gives me this output, for example:

```
**case_type**     **claim_type**                 
service           service                         2
                  supplier_service                1
                  service_not_used                2
chargeback        service                         6
                  local_charges                   1
```

I would also like to have have the sum of the output per case_type. Something like:

```
**case_type**     **claim_type**                 
service           service                         2
                  supplier_service                1
                  service_not_used                2
                  total:                          5
chargeback        service                         6
                  local_charges                   1
                  total:                          7
```

It doesn't necessarily has to be in this last output format, a column with the (aggregated) totals per case_type is also fine.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data?

Comment: @ScottBoston Yup, I just added some sample input data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'case_type':['Service']*20+['chargeback']*9,'claim_type':['service']*5+['local_charges']*5+['service_not_used']*5+['supplier_service']*5+['service']*8+['local_charges']})

df_out = df.groupby(by=("case_type", "claim_type"))["case_type"].count()
```

Let use `pd.concat`, `sum` with level parameter, and `assign`:

```
(pd.concat([df_out.to_frame(),
           df_out.sum(level=0).to_frame()
                 .assign(claim_type= "total")
                 .set_index('claim_type', append=True)])
  .sort_index())
```

Output:

```
                             case_type
case_type  claim_type                 
Service    local_charges             5
           service                   5
           service_not_used          5
           supplier_service          5
           total                    20
chargeback local_charges             1
           service                   8
           total                     9
```

Comment: Thanks. Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
df = case_claim_type.groupby(by=("case_type", "claim_type"))["case_type"].count()
print (df)
case_type   claim_type      
chargeback  local_charges       1
            service             1
service     service             2
            supplier_service    1
Name: case_type, dtype: int64
```

You can create new `DataFrame` by aggregate `sum` and add `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
df1 = df.sum(level=0)
#same as
#df1 = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
new_cols= list(zip(df1.index.get_level_values(0),['total'] * len(df.index)))
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
print (df1)
chargeback  total    2
service     total    3
Name: case_type, dtype: int64
```

Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together and last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df2 = pd.concat([df,df1]).sort_index()
print (df2)
case_type   claim_type      
chargeback  local_charges       1
            service             1
            total               2
service     service             2
            supplier_service    1
            total               3
Name: case_type, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is very intuitive. I've tried this and it works very well. However, I marked the other answer as solution as the answer is a bit more concise.

Comment: @eppe2000 - If you get 2 nice answers, it is always hard ;) But it is up you what solution use ;) good luck!

Comment: Hey @jezrael - Necromancing this a little bit, I know, but I was looking around for an answer close to this one but where the Total can be done for more than just addition; say, means as well. Any clue?

Comment: @cjcrm - Then change `df1 = df.sum(level=0)` to `df1 = df.mean(level=0)`

Comment: @jezrael right, but what if my groupby uses, say, groupby(...).agg({'case_type':['sum','mean']), what would be the best way to get the case_type's correct values for each agg function applied?

Comment: @cjcrm - I think then need filtering and for each dataframe use correct aggregate function. But maybe the best is create question with sample data and expected output.